# VB.Net - Noncooperative decimal in string

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a calculator WinForm in VB.  I have a label used to display the output "Result".  My problem comes when trying to add a "." to my label string.  Example: I will type 355.5 and until the 5 is pressed after it, my string is showing up as .355  After the last 5 is pressed, it jumps into the correct location.  I have exhausted my debugging skill and now am just going crazy.  Anyone encounter this before?

Here's my entire code so far (ignore unfinished functions)

```
Public Class MyCalc

Private bDecFlag As Boolean
Private sMathOp As String

Private Sub ModeSel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ModeSel.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        Me.Width = 360
    ElseIf ModeSel.SelectedIndex > 2 Then
        Me.Width = 590
    Else
        Me.Width = 250
    End If

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        For iCount As Integer = 0 To 9
            Me.Controls("Digit" & iCount).Enabled = True
        Next
    End If

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        For iCount As Integer = 2 To 9
            Me.Controls("Digit" & iCount).Enabled = False
        Next
    End If

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        For iCount As Integer = 0 To 7
            Me.Controls("Digit" & iCount).Enabled = True
        Next
        Digit8.Enabled = False
        Digit9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        For iCount As Integer = 0 To 9
            Me.Controls("Digit" & iCount).Enabled = True
        Next
        For iCount As Integer = Asc("A") To Asc("F")
            Me.Controls("Alpha" & Chr(iCount)).Enabled = True
        Next
        For iCount As Integer = Asc("G") To Asc("Z")
            Me.Controls("Alpha" & Chr(iCount)).Enabled = False
        Next
    End If

    If ModeSel.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        For iCount As Integer = 0 To 9
            Me.Controls("Digit" & iCount).Enabled = True
        Next

        For iCount As Integer = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
            Me.Controls("Alpha" & Chr(iCount)).Enabled = True
        Next
        AlphaA.Enabled = False
        AlphaE.Enabled = False
        AlphaI.Enabled = False
        AlphaO.Enabled = False
        AlphaU.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Digit0_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit0.Click
    UpdateResult(0)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit1.Click
    UpdateResult(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit2.Click
    UpdateResult(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit3.Click
    UpdateResult(3)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit4.Click
    UpdateResult(4)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit5.Click
    UpdateResult(5)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit6.Click
    UpdateResult(6)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit7.Click
    UpdateResult(7)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit8.Click
    UpdateResult(8)
End Sub

Private Sub Digit9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Digit9.Click
    UpdateResult(9)
End Sub

Private Sub DecBut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DecBut.Click
    If bDecFlag = False Then
        If Result.Text = "0" Then
            Result.Text = "0."
            bDecFlag = True
        Else
            Result.Text = Result.Text + "."
            bDecFlag = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClrBut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClrBut.Click
    Result.Text = 0
    bDecFlag = False
End Sub

Private Sub DelBut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DelBut.Click
    If Result.Text = "0" Then
    ElseIf Result.Text.Substring(Result.Text.Length - 1) = "." Then
        Result.Text = Result.Text.Substring(0, Result.Text.Length - 1)
        bDecFlag = False
    Else
        Result.Text = Result.Text.Substring(0, Result.Text.Length - 1)
        If Result.Text = "" Then
            Result.Text = "0"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyCalc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.NumPad0
            Digit0_Click(Digit0, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad1
            Digit1_Click(Digit1, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad2
            Digit2_Click(Digit2, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad3
            Digit3_Click(Digit3, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad4
            Digit4_Click(Digit4, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad5
            Digit5_Click(Digit5, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad6
            Digit6_Click(Digit6, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad7
            Digit7_Click(Digit7, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad8
            Digit8_Click(Digit8, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.NumPad9
            Digit9_Click(Digit9, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.Back
            DelBut_Click(DelBut, New EventArgs)
        Case Keys.Decimal
            DecBut_Click(DecBut, New EventArgs)

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub MyCalc_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bDecFlag = False
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateResult(ByVal sNum As String)
    If Result.Text = "0" Then
        Result.Text = sNum
    Else
        Result.Text &= sNum
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Just after `Result.Text = Result.Text + "."` ,could you write Msgbox(Result.Text) and tell us the result in the messagebox.

Comment: Message box says 2.  but display in label still says .2

Comment: So the problem is on how you add the text in the textbox. Now, try to replace `Result.Text = Result.Text + '.'` by `UpdateResult(".")`

Comment: Same results.  I do not think the problem lies in how I am adding as my update function works fine with digits. This is just throwing me for a loop. I even did a redundant Result.Text = Result.Text and still the issue remains.

Comment: As I'm eager to know what's wrong in here, can you upload the your project file in http://tinyupload.com/ and tell us the link to download it?

Comment: Quick question so I don't waste your time.  If I upload the solution file is that adequate for you to open and get all the code? Or do you need bin and obj too?

Comment: Yes I need all. Zip the file please

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Here is full zip. [link] (http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51063120726439915970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the long debugging, I found out that you are using the Label/Textbox **RightToLeft** property set to **yes**. Nothing is wrong with it really, but it can't handle special characters including decimal points, commas, etc. properly. The workaround for this is to reverse what we have expected - to reverse the string concatenation.

```
Result.Text = "." & Result.Text
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That had me going crazy.

Comment: Me too. I think solving a problem for an hour with just a simple solution is an overkill for us. lol

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing entire code I'm not exactly sure but I think there might be something wrong with string concatenation. 
Try changing into this:

```
Result.Text = Result.Text & "."
```

Comment: Changed line to above and same result.  Would it be more helpful if I uploaded the entire code? It is just a mess right now because it is only half finished.

Comment: Post parts involved in formatting/displaying Result.text

Comment: Just realized the designer file probably has nothing to do with formatting/displaying text. Can you please provide more detailed instructions on what I should upload. I am new to visual studio environment.

Comment: @mschmidt9026 What you have posted is the designer code and not the .vb one. Post the code like the first one you posted in your question.